# Google Cloud Functions - Count documents by id and timestamp

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I am a frontend developer working on some backend stuff in a private side project aka. I am signed up for trouble.

So this is my first cloud function. I am using typescript.

I want it to:

- Be called when a document is created in the collection [WORKS]
- Calculate the start of the day in GMT the document was uploaded on according to the time (type is timestamp) I add to the document when uploading it using the FieldValue.serverTimestamp() [WORKS]
- Count the number of documents which were created today and have the same id as the document we are calling the cloud function for [DOESN'T WORK]

Here's my code:

```
import * as functions from "firebase-functions";

import * as admin from "firebase-admin";
admin.initializeApp();

exports.countPrevious = functions.firestore
.document("entries/{documentId}")
.onCreate(async (snap, context) => {
try {
  //Get current id
  const id = snap.data().id;

  //Calculate start and end of day the entry was uploaded on (in server time)
  const startOfUploadDay = snap
    .data()
    .uploadFirestoreServerTimestamp.toDate()
    .setUTCHours(0, 0, 0, 0);

  //Query for all entries that happened for this id, today
  const queryResult = await admin.firestore()
  .collection("entries")
  .where("id", "==", id)
  .where("uploadFirestoreServerTimestamp", ">", startOfUploadDay)
  .get();

  const count = queryResult.size;

  return snap.ref.update({ previousEntries: count });
} catch (error) {
  return snap.ref.update({ status: 200 }); //200 is the code for cancelled
}
});
```

What am I doing wrong?

Also, is this the most efficient way of doing this? Is there a way I can just use the count() function?

Much love in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a `catch` block but you don't log the error message. So you miss the error message explaining that, for your query, you need to build a composite index.

If you do

```
} catch (error) {
  console.log(error);
  return snap.ref.update({ status: 200 }); //200 is the code for cancelled
}
```

the error message will be displayed in the [Google Cloud Console](https://console.cloud.google.com/logs) under the "Logging" section and will give you an URL to call to automatically create the index, e.g. `The query requires an index. You can create it here: https://console.firebase.google.com/v1/r/project/....`

> Is doing `queryResult.size` the most efficient way of doing this? Is
> there a way I can just use the `count()` function?

No, using the `size` property of the `QuerySnapshot` means that you fetch **all** the documents corresponding to the `Query` which costs one read per document.

It's indeed much better and cheaper to use the `count()` method as follows:

```
const queryResult = await admin.firestore()
            .collection("entries")
            .where("id", "==", id)
            .where("uploadFirestoreServerTimestamp", ">", startOfUploadDay)
            .count()
            .get();

const count = queryResult.data().count;
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks you so much for your answer. Very very helpful. I get a "Property 'data' does not exist on type 'QuerySnapshot<DocumentData>'." even though I 1:1 copied your code over. What's wrong here?

Comment: Hi, there was an error in my code, it’s corrected now. BTW the `count()` documentation is at https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/aggregation-queries#node.js

Comment: Perfect Renaud, thank you so much. Elaborate and concise answer that catered for everything I asked for. Made my day.